# How can I get `zip` to use relative paths in a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, zip

Normally I use `zip` command with:

```
zip -r my_arch.zip my_folder
```

Now I am using `zip` in an bash script in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash    
OUT=$1
NAME=$2
zip -r -q $OUT/$NAME $OUT/$NAME
```

I call the script with:

```
./mySrcipt /home/edevise/foo myFiles
```

Opening the resulting zip file shows, that the full path was used to zip the folder `foo`. E.g. opening the zip file shows the `home` folder and I need to navigate through all subsequent folders until I see my folder `foo`.

How to **adapt the script** to zip the folder `foo`, only?

PS: Please don't wonder about the sense of the script. It is just an example to show the problem.

Comment: "Please don't wonder", isn't he right thing to do here as we need a sample output and your real code to able to help you!

Comment: And may be you should add `set -x` at the top of your script to see what it does or doesn't do!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473115/command-to-zip-a-directory-using-a-specific-directory-as-the-root

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: I really think that it is not a good idea to paste hundreds of lines of code here. The core problem is described very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only relative paths in the zip file, you should add a `cd` command to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
OUT="$1"
NAME="$2"
cd "$OUT"
zip -r -q "$NAME" "$NAME"
cd -
```

Comment: You don't need to cd back (`cd -`) at the end of a script.